# Get client IP address for WCF, post operation

Tags: wcf, client, ip-address, webinvoke

I am trying to determine the client's IP address following this link: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/21/get-the-clients-address-in-wcf/

> In .Net 3.0 there was not a reliable way to obtain the address of the
>   client connecting to a WCF service.  In .Net 3.5 a new property was
>   introduced called RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.  This property gives
>   you the IP address and port that the client connection came into the
>   service on. Obtaining the this information is pretty straight forward.
>   Just pull it from the IncomingMessageProperties of the current
>   OperationContext by the RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name and access
>   the Address and Port properties.

```
> [ServiceContract] public interface IMyService {
>     [OperationContract]
>     string GetAddressAsString(); }
> 
> public class MyService : IMyService {
>     public string GetAddressAsString()
>     {
>         RemoteEndpointMessageProperty clientEndpoint =
>             OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[
>             RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
> 
>         return String.Format(
>             "{0}:{1}",
>             clientEndpoint.Address, clientEndpoint.Port);
>     } }
```

> Things to note:
>
> 1. This property only works on http and tcp transports.  On all other
>      transports such as MSMQ and NamedPipes, this property will not be
>      available.
> 2. The address and port are reported by the socket or http.sys
>      of the service’s machine.  So if the client came in over a VPN or some
>      other proxy that modified the address, that new address will be
>      represented instead of the client’s local address.  This is desirable
>      and important because this is the address and port that the service
>      sees the client as, not as the client sees itself as.  This also means
>      that there could be some spoofing going on.  A client or something in
>      between the client and server could spoof an address. So, do not use
>      the address or port for any security decisions unless you add in some
>      other custom checking mechanisms.
> 3. If you are using duplexing on your
>      service, then not only will the service have this property populated
>      for the client, but the client will also have this property populated
>      for the service for each call from that service.

I have operationContracts of WebInvoke/Post and WebGet. The code works when the client request is a WebGet. But when the client request is a WebInvoke, I will get the WCF host IP. Any solution? Thanks.

Here is the interface

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = RestTemplate.hello_get)]
Stream hello_get();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = RestTemplate.hello_post)]
Stream hello_post();

// Code for getting IP
private string getClientIP()
{
    //WebOperationContext webContext = WebOperationContext.Current;

    OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;

    MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;

    RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty =

    messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name]

    as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
    return endpointProperty.Address;
}

public Stream hello_get()
{
    string ip = getClientIP();
    ...
}

public Stream hello_post()
{
    string ip = getClientIP();
    ...
}
```

Comment: You may want to show what you have tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: I agree with James.  I don't see why this wouldn't work for a WebInvoke.  Can you provide some code (and configuration) so we can how you're handling it?

Comment: Thanks. I have added some code as show above.

Comment: If this doesn't work you should create simple example which reproduces issue and post it to Microsoft Connect. For me this is a bug because there is no reason why GET should work and POST not.

Comment: The link is dead, so its hard to reference what the code is suppose to do now.

Comment: Did you check by enabling asp.net compatibility. Also, you will have to check if there is any redirection happening in the course of processing this request, in kind of a load balancing scenario.

Comment: You may need to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311684/cant-get-proper-client-ip-address-on-server-side-wcf

Comment: is there a any firewall?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the HttpContext? It's not available in all WCF modes but this could work depending on your environment:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(
                    "Who's calling? IP address: '{0}', Name: '{1}', User Agent: '{2}', URL: '{3}'.",
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName,
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
            }
```